# Как телеграм ботом отослать сообщение со стикером?

Tags: python, aiogram

впервые делаю телеграм бота на python (aiogram)
Мне надо что бы при написании команды /start приходил в ответ стикера и текст, но вылазит только что-то одно
python

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start']) 
async def stik(message:types.Sticker):
     await bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
 
 @dp.message_handler(commands=['start']) 
 async def begin(message:types.Message):
     await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет друг!")
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, что бы по одной команде отправлялся стикер и сообщение

Вот так:

[image: 123]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде как в телеграме невозможно в одно сообщение впихнуть и стикер и текст. Можешь сам проверить, ты не сможешь как юзер отправить их в одном message.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start']) 
async def begin(message: types.Message):
     await message.answer_sticker(sticker="https://github.com/TelegramBots/book/raw/master/src/docs/sticker-fred.webp")
     await message.answer("Привет друг!")
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы идеально сделали!!